# $scope not defined in AngularJS exercise

Tags: angularjs

I'm following along with Dan Wahlin's "AngularJS Fundamentals in 60-ish Minutes" on Youtube. Per changes to AngularJS 1.2 and after, I've added a call to "angular-route.min.js" (and I'm aware that I need to use min-safe syntax below as a result), included 'ngRoute' as a module dependency, and added $scope as a controller dependency. The code runs with no errors until it gets to the $scope.addCustomer() function at the bottom, at which point it throws a "$scope is not defined" error. I've looked through similar posts but haven't seen the same problem. How do I have to word addCustomer() so that it's contained within the $scope object, min-safe, and doesn't throw an error? Do custom functions require a dependency injection, as well (if that can even be done)?

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demoApp">
    <!--- This is how you integrate with partials (views)... --->
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <!-- placeholder for the views -->
            <div ng-view></div>

            <!-- normally would put this in it's own js file and call with script src="" -->
            <script>
                var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

                demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider
                    .when("/",
                            {
                                controller:"simpleController",
                                templateURL:"partials/view1.htm"
                            })
                    .when("/partial2",
                            {
                                controller:"simpleController",
                                templateURL:"partials/view2.htm"
                            })
                    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/"});
                });


                demoApp.controller('simpleController', ['$scope', function(sc) {
                    sc.customers = [
                            {name:"David Jones", city:"Phoenix"},
                            {name:"James Riley", city:"Atlanta"},
                            {name:"Heedy Wahlin", city:"Chandler"},
                            {name:"Thomas Winter", city:"Seattle"}
                        ];
                }]);

                $scope.addCustomer = function(){
                    $scope.customers.push(
                        {name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city}
                    );
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope` functions are defined inside of controllers (where the scope exists).

Your `addCustomer` function should go inside the controller where the scope is injected.

Here's how it should look:

```
demoApp.controller('simpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.customers = [
             {name:"David Jones", city:"Phoenix"},
             {name:"James Riley", city:"Atlanta"},
             {name:"Heedy Wahlin", city:"Chandler"},
             {name:"Thomas Winter", city:"Seattle"}
         ];

     $scope.addCustomer = function() {
         $scope.customers.push(
             {name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city}
         );
     };
 }]);
```